# Add Icon in Navigation Drawer Manually

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

im confuse to add icon beside title on navigation drawer, anyone know how to do that? 
im following this lik for create some nav drawer [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) ,

this my code

FragmentDrawer.java

```
public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

    private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
    private View containerView;
    private static String[] titles = null;
    private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;

    public FragmentDrawer() {

    }

    public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
        this.drawerListener = listener;
    }

    public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
        List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();



        // preparing navigation drawer items
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
            navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
            data.add(navItem);
        }
        return data;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // drawer labels
        titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating view layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

        adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        return layout;
    }


    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }


    }

    public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
        public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

string.xml

```
<string name="nav_item_home">Home</string>
<string name="nav_item_friends">Friends</string>
<string name="nav_item_notifications">Messages</string>
<string name="nav_item_calculator">BMI Calculator</string>
<string name="nav_item_listview">Test Json</string>
<string name="nav_item_testabs">Test Tabs</string>


<!-- navigation drawer item labels  -->
<string-array name="nav_drawer_labels">
    <item>@string/nav_item_home</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_friends</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_notifications</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_calculator</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_listview</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_testabs</item>
</string-array>

<array name="nav_drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/arm1</item>
    <item>@drawable/abs2</item>
    <item>@drawable/back</item>
    <item>@drawable/leg</item>
    <item>@drawable/shoulder</item>
    <item>@drawable/achest</item>
</array>
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FriendsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_notifications);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CalculatorFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_calculator);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new MovieFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_listview);
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new TabFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_testabs);
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

NavDrawwerItem.java

```
public class NavDrawerItem {
private boolean showNotify;
private String title;
private int icon;

public NavDrawerItem() {

}

public NavDrawerItem(boolean showNotify, String title, int icon) {
    this.showNotify = showNotify;
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public boolean isShowNotify() {
    return showNotify;
}

public void setShowNotify(boolean showNotify) {
    this.showNotify = showNotify;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getIcon(){
    return this.icon;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setIcon(int icon){
    this.icon = icon;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? post your `drawerlist` xml here.

Comment: @Yashasvi thanks here the code nav_drawe_list.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Hi, it's not readable here. you should edit your question and post your code there.

Comment: hi thanks for answer, i think the best way following this https://androidbelieve.com/navigation-drawer-with-swipe-tabs-using-design-support-library/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Imageview in your drawerlist xml,and make your adapter custom and set your icons,

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:paddingTop="8sp"
    android:paddingBottom="8sp"
    android:paddingLeft="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer btw,
and finaly im using design widget from android studio default for easy customize